# Exposing an instance method to Objective-C within an extension method

Tags: xcode, selector, extension-methods, swift3

I've got an application that uses UIKeyboardWillShow & Hide notifications in a few different controllers. I've decided to try to consolidate the logic required to move the view with the keyboard into an extension based on a protocol.

**Here's my protocol**

```
public protocol KeyboardType : class {
    func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification)
    func keyboardWillHide(_ sender: Notification)
}
```

Next, I added an extension to my new protocol so that all I need to do is implement my "KeyboardType protocol and I'll gain access to the necessary functionality to move my view with my keyboard:

**Here's my extension**

```
public extension KeyboardType where Self: UIViewController {

    func addObservers() { 
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Self.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)
    }

    func removeObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: self.view.window)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: self.view.window)

    }

    func keyboardWillHide(_ sender: Notification) {
        let userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any] = (sender as NSNotification).userInfo!
        let keyboardSize: CGSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
        self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification) {
        let userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any] = sender.userInfo!

        let keyboardSize: CGSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size
        let offset: CGSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue.size

        if keyboardSize.height == offset.height {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                })
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - offset.height
            })
        }
    }

}
```

**The problem**

The problem is the compiler is asking me to add @objc to my keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide methods. When I allow Xcode to add the keywords, the compiler immediately asks me to remove the @objc keywords.

[image]

> Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'keyboardWillShow'
>   that is not exposed to Objective-C

### My Question

How do I expose keyboardWillShow to Objective-C in this situation?

**or**

Is there a better way to accomplish the same task?

Comment: Note: not related to the selector but your method as it is right now will crash with beta 6. You need to cast it to NSValue `(notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size`

Comment: @LeoDabus this exact code works perfectly inside my view controller in beta 6

Comment: Well thats weird i will double check. I had smilar code that was crashing when casting to AnyObject when i updated to beta 6

Comment: I figured it out. Your method was working because you were casting first to NSNotification. If you don't cast to NSNotification and you need to do as I suggested otherwise it would crash your app

Comment: Your screen shot shows that you are importing only Foundation, but you know you need to import UIKit to use `UIViewController` in your code. Some errors (including such missing import) might be preventing Xcode to progress code analysis, so showing old error messages.

Comment: @OOPer I was really hoping that would fix the problem but I'm still getting the same issue. :/

Comment: Sorry, I was missing some things. Even if I removed the diagnostics from Xcode editor, I get this error: `non-'@objc' method 'keyboardWillShow' does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol 'KeyboardType'` which I do know well... My answer fixes just small part of your issue, and cannot achieve what you are intending. You should accept the Leo Dabus's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a different approach there extending UIViewController as follow:

```
protocol KeyboardController {
    func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification)
    func keyboardWillHide(_ sender: Notification)
}
```

---

```
extension UIViewController: KeyboardController {
    func addObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)),
                                               name:.UIKeyboardWillShow,
                                               object: view.window)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)),
                                               name:.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                                               object: view.window)
    }

    func removeObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: view.window)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: view.window)
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("---> keyboardWillHide")

        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
        let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        print("keyboardSize", keyboardSize)

    }

    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("---> keyboardWillShow")
        guard

            let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size,
            let offset = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        else { return }

        if keyboardSize.height == offset.height {
            if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
                })
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - offset.height
            })
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addObservers()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

---

Another option and the one I like most is to subclass UIViewController:

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        addObservers()
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        removeObservers()
    }

    func addObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: view.window)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: view.window)
    }

    func removeObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: view.window)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: view.window)
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("---> keyboardWillHide")
        if let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size.height {
            print("keyboardHeight", keyboardHeight)
            view.frame.origin.y += keyboardHeight
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("---> keyboardWillShow")
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size.height,
            let offsetHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size.height {
            print("userInfo", userInfo)
            print("keyboardHeight", keyboardHeight)
            print("offsetHeight", offsetHeight)
            if keyboardHeight == offsetHeight {
                if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                        self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardHeight
                    })
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                    self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardHeight - offsetHeight
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class ViewController:  KeyboardViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: I had considered extending UIViewController initially, but I was trying to avoid adding blanket functionality to the UIViewController type. I think this is an acceptable solution but I'll need to re-word my question if I accept this as my answer. (Which I'll probably do)

Comment: I'm accepting this as the best solution to my problem. I'll review the Dropbox file you sent tomorrow and revise my question afterwords. Thanks again Leo

Comment: took a quick look at your file, the subclassing route is a good solution as well

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?:

```
@objc public protocol KeyboardType {
    func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification)
    func keyboardWillHide(_ sender: Notification)
}
```

You also need to import UIKit

Comment: Yes. When I add this the compiler tried adding @objc before my two functions and when I add them, it then tells me to remove them.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu Have you tried adding it to the protocol instead of the methods?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu, an odd behaviour. In my beta 6, Xcode does not complain anything about `@objc` with the protocol shown above. (Though you may need to fix some other parts of your code.) Re-input my code above and try clean-build.

Comment: @LeoDabus I've added an image and a brief explanation of whats happening. The solution above is something I tried before I posted.